# In a JoinBlock, receive a Target when the other Target is filled

Tags: c#, .net, tpl-dataflow

I'm connecting a JoinBlock to a WriteOnceBlock and a BufferBlock to fill Targets 1 and 2. My goal is that every time the JoinBlock receives a message from the BufferBlock , it also requests the value that the WriteOnceBlock is holding.

My first guess was that I could add a ContinueWith delegate to the Target2 Completion event, but that's not quite right - I need to attach to something like a Filled event that doesn't seem to exist.

I also tried using the join block in non-greedy mode as a last-ditch effort, but that didn't change the output.

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Example:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var writeOnceBlockTest = new WriteOnceBlock<int>(i => i);
        var queueBlockTest = new BufferBlock<string>();
        var joinBlockTest = new JoinBlock<int, string>();
        var actionBlockTest = new ActionBlock<System.Tuple<int, string>>(tuple => Console.WriteLine($"I received int {tuple.Item1} and string {tuple.Item2}."));

        writeOnceBlockTest.LinkTo(joinBlockTest.Target1);
        queueBlockTest.LinkTo(joinBlockTest.Target2, new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion = true});
        joinBlockTest.LinkTo(actionBlockTest, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        writeOnceBlockTest.Post(3);
        queueBlockTest.Post("String1");
        queueBlockTest.Post("String2");
        writeOnceBlockTest.Post(4);
        writeOnceBlockTest.Post(5);
        queueBlockTest.Post("String3");
        queueBlockTest.Post("String4");
        queueBlockTest.Complete();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**Desired output:**

> I received int 3 and string String1.
>
> I received int 3 and string String2.
>
> I received int 3 and string String3.
>
> I received int 3 and string String4.

**Actual output:**

> I received int 3 and string String1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JoinBlock` isn't the right choice here although it does seem like the perfect fit. The `WriteOnceBlock`, as you've found, only offers it's value once. However, you can read that value many times. With this you can use a `TransformBlock` to get the behavior your looking for.

```
public class JoinFlow
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestWriteOnceBlock()
    {
        var writeOnceBlockTest = new WriteOnceBlock<int>(i => i);
        var queueBlockTest = new BufferBlock<string>();
        var transformBlockTest = new TransformBlock<string, Tuple<int, string>>(async str => Tuple.Create(await writeOnceBlockTest.ReceiveAsync(), str));
        var actionBlockTest = new ActionBlock<Tuple<int, string>>(tuple => Console.WriteLine($"I received int {tuple.Item1} and string {tuple.Item2}."));

        queueBlockTest.LinkTo(transformBlockTest, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlockTest.LinkTo(actionBlockTest, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        writeOnceBlockTest.Post(3);
        queueBlockTest.Post("String1");
        queueBlockTest.Post("String2");
        writeOnceBlockTest.Post(4);
        writeOnceBlockTest.Post(5);
        queueBlockTest.Post("String3");
        queueBlockTest.Post("String4");
        queueBlockTest.Complete();
        await actionBlockTest.Completion;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
I received int 3 and string String1.
I received int 3 and string String2.
I received int 3 and string String3.
I received int 3 and string String4.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I was stuck thinking I needed to call Receive() on a TargetBlock passing in the SourceBlock as a parameter. But because there's no Receive() method on each of the Targets on a JoinBlock, I felt stuck. This is perfect though!

Comment: I'm having a bit of an issue with using this solution - hoping you can help. For whatever reason, the transform block behaves as a bit of an odd one out in the chain - it doesn't propagate completion signals (despite having that option set on the link) and it doesn't seem to pass messages on down the graph. If I remove the ReceiveAsync() call, it behaves has expected. Do you know if there are any side effects to ReceiveAsync that could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: @setagana That is odd behavior, the `ReceiveAsync` call itself would not cause those effects. In the little example in the answer the `TransformBlock` is linked to an `ActionBlock` and `Completion` & messages are propagated correctly. It could be that the call to `await ReceiveAsync` is hanging for some reason preventing propagation of messages and complete. Another option is there could be a block with outbound messages that's preventing proper flow, it's hard to say. I'd need to inspect your pipeline in more detail to say more. Maybe a new question would be the best way to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah I can't see any obvious reason for this behaviour either, @JSteward. I have raised a separate question (with a LOT more detail) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52219108/5799778